# What is ^R in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm trying to run my node program via the keyboard shortcut provided by WebStorm.

When I use the `^` to run the shortcut as indicated nothing happens.
Am I interpreting the keyboard shortcut correctly ?

[image: Keyboard shortcut]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> at the same time.

*edit:* A downvote before my post could even refresh. Impressive.

Anyways, I don't use webstorm, but if I'm guessing correctly, they're just using [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for their shortcuts.